# What CPU instruction set extensions does Mathematica support?

Tags: implementation-details, hardware

Most CPUs in desktops and laptops nowadays are backwards compatible with the x86-64 instruction sets.  But newer CPUs also have additional instruction set extensions like AVX 2, FMA3, and BMI/BMI2 which require support from software to be useful.  For compiled languages, that is often as easy as enabling the appropriate flags when compiling.  For interpreted software like Mathematica, though, making full use of new instruction sets requires support from the implementation.
Does anyone know what CPU instructions Mathematica supports beyond the core x86-64?
Thanks

Comment: Mathematica uses the MKL library which I *think* chooses the best implementation for your CPU at runtime. That is, it *can* make use of new instructions while being compatible with old CPUs.

Comment: It also uses GMP, which I know has the same feature.  Search for "fat binary" on this page: https://gmplib.org/manual/Build-Options.html

Comment: *Real* usage of these instructions, that actually improves performance significantly rather than just having the possibility for them to appear in the machine code, is about far more than setting compiler switches. I suspect WRI wishes to keep *Mathematica* compatible with processors that do not support e.g. AVX2, not to mention that it is not really needed anyway, except for linear algebra or other heavily numerical operations. MKL is used in these cases, and it supports basically everything Intel processors offer by runtime dispatch, as Szabolcs says.

Comment: @OleksandrR. so we have an unanswered question here, with answer all in comments. Why not compile this into a real answer?

Comment: @Ruslan I don't know which compiler (version/switches) Mma is compiled with on all platforms, so it's difficult to say with any authority; and we certainly can't recompile it with different compiler/switches to test the performance differences. My comment was more along the lines of: we don't really know, but one shouldn't be too concerned about this because the performance impact of using or not using these instruction set extensions will probably be negligible anyway, judging from my own experience. They are used (to good effect) where it actually matters, in the vendor libraries.